# How to send WordPress loop data to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops

I am creating a video gallery with an embedded video on a Word Press site and I want to use jQuery to change the URL that's in embedded video link. So, all the video posts will be at the bottom of the page, and when a video is clicked it will display that video at the top of the page.

I have a for loop which displays all the video posts, and I added an attribute of "data-link" to the post title which I want to populate with the_title()

The title will be the URL of the video that I want to embed

Here is my code -

```
<div class="embedded-video">
  <iframe width="420" height="315"
  src="youtubeLink" id="big-video">
  </iframe> 
</div>

<?php
  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'cat' => '2', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => 9
    );
  $product_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
?>

<?php foreach ( $product_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<div class="gallery-card-text">
  <h2 data-link="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="video-link"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
</div>
```

```
$('.video-link').click(function () {
  let newLink = $(".video-link").attr('data-link');
  console.log(newLink);
  $('#big-video').attr('src', newLink);
});
```

When I inspect the data-link attribute for each post, it displays properly, e.g. data-link for Post 2 is Post 2's title, Post 3's title, etc.

But when I click on any of the titles, my console log shows the title for the first post only.

How can I get it to log the title of the post that's clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change...

```
$(".video-link").attr('data-link');
```

to...

```
$(this).attr('data-link');
```

The issue is that you are clicking an element, going into an event handler for that element, finding **all the links**, and grabbing the data-link off the first one.  Instead of finding the element that was clicked, use the `this` that will already reference the element the event hander is bound to, and originated from.